# Time Limit exceeded in travis ci builds : How to restart?

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I submitted a pull request and travis ci says:

No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

The build has been terminated.

So how do I restart my build?

I searched on this and found that there should be a restart button at the top right corner. But I did not find it in my case.

Comment: You probably have to be a collaborator or own of the GitHub project in order for that button to appear.

Comment: I am not one. So how do I restart my build now?

Comment: Either update your pull request or ask someone with permission to restart it.

Comment: Actually the owner of repo has asked me to simply restart the build. What do you specifically mean by updating the pull request?

Comment: @SaurabhShah Push to the branch you're requesting to be pulled